# Deleting a status tweet accidentally published on Twitter

Tags: twitter

I accidentally posted to Twitter what was supposed to be a direct message. Now, people are replying to me and asking me about that tweet.

Can I delete it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can delete your old tweets, just click on the "trash can" icon. However they may remain around for a while in searches and the like. They'll also stay on people's Twitter home page until they refresh the page.

> Voila! Gone forever... almost. Deleted updates sometimes hang out in Twitter search. They will clear with time.

[Source](http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/109-tweets-messages/articles/18906-how-to-delete-a-tweet)

Comment: I might be wrong, but they might also remain in desktop clients.

Comment: @Alex - good point. I suppose there it depends on how often they refresh themselves and whether they delete old messages or not.

Answer (score 5):

When you mouse over the tweet it will darken and "Delete" will appear in the lower right hand corner, just click that. A confirm box will appear warning you that the delete cannot be undone.

Answer (score 3):

if you wait too long to delete the status, chances are good it's going to stay on google cache and/or twitter-indexing sites for a while. once it's out there, it's pretty hard to get rid of permanently.